# How to change a dataset name

Tags: google-bigquery

I created a dataset in BigQuery. Unfortunately, it is unclear how to rename it? I clicked on the arrow in the right side of the dataset name, but I can not see any option to rename it.

Comment: you cannot rename dataset. what you are trying to accomplish? you might have other way to get there

Comment: Just chose a bad name for dataset. I can see that I can create a new dataset, then copy all the tables from the old to the new. But I thought there might be some shortcut I am missing.

Comment: yes - this is the way: create new dataset > copy tables > delete old dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to rename a dataset when using in BigQuery. Instead, it it required to recreate the resource and copy the old information into the new dataset, as mentioned in the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#renaming_datasets).

> Currently, you cannot change the name of an existing dataset, and you
>   cannot copy a dataset and give it a new name. If you need to change
>   the dataset name, follow these steps to recreate the dataset:
>
> 1. [Create a new dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#create-dataset) and specify the new name.
> 2. [Copy the tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copy-table) from the old dataset to the new one.
> 3. [Recreate the views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-views#copying_a_view) in the new dataset.
> 4. [Delete](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#delete-dataset) the old dataset to avoid additional storage costs.